# How to write $H = \{x: \cos(x) > 0\}$ as the union of the intervals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have $\dfrac {1}{2}\left( 4\pi k\pm k \right)  ,k\in \mathbb{Z}$. But I don't understand how to represent it as the union of the intervals.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29%3E0

Comment: Draw the graph of $\cos x$ and indicate the points where the function equals to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\cos $ is $2\pi$ periodic and positive on the interval $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ so

$$H=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z} \left(-\frac\pi2+2k\pi,\frac\pi2+2k\pi\right)$$

Comment: I like the way you expressed the union of such intervals much better than the way I tried!